# create directory in docker by python script

Tags: python, docker

I try to create a directory in docker by python script.

I tried:

```
import os

def create_table(table_name, csv_path):
    os.system("docker cp " + csv_path + " 429c027af50d:/root/go/src/github.com/uber/aresdb/examples/")
    os.system("cd aresdb-docker")
    os.system("docker start 429c027af50d")
    os.system("docker exec -it 429c027af50d bash")
    os.system("cd /root/go/src/github.com/uber/aresdb/examples/")
    os.system("mkdir " + table_name)

create_table("detections", "detections.csv")
```

The problem is that the directory is created outside the docker.

How can I create a directory in docker?

Comment: put the instructions inside your docker file?

Comment: *Never* construct a command using string interpolation like this to pass to `os.system()`: if I'm motivated, I can construct a `csv_path` that will give me unlimited root access to the system (especially if I know I can run `docker` commands).  Look at the `subprocess` module and its call path that takes an array of words, which is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

You're running mkdir on your host OS.

You don't need `docker exec -it 429c027af50d bash`

Just do `"docker exec 429c027af50d mkdir " + table_name`, where table name is the full path to the directory

FWIW, I would recommend a shell script rather than python for such simple bash commands

Answer (score 1):

Why is the directory created outside the docker container?
 - this line `os.system("docker exec -it 429c027af50d bash")` gets executed in a sub-shell and once it succeeds that subshell is destroyed whereas on cli we see that the we are changing into the container's shell. So anything after the mentioned line is just running on your system's shell and not in the container's shell.

- in order to create the folder use this instead:

  `os.system("docker exec -it 429c027af50d mkdir /root/go/src/github.com/uber/aresdb/examples/" + table_name)`